# doubles converted into single digits for an array

Tags: c++, arrays, double

I am writing Luhns Algorithm and I need to input a 10 digit number, I was thinking of using a double since it's large enough to hold a 10 digit number but then I need to convert the double into single digits and input them in an array.

Here's an example of what I want to do:

```
input a 10 digit number
double num=7992739871
convert to single digits
int *array={7,9,9,2,7,3,9,8,7,1}
```

now I don't know if inputting the number as a double is the best choice but it seemed like the most obvious choice, any help is appreciated!

Comment: in general, `array[n] = ( num / 10^(9-n) ) % 10`

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler way to do this is to just read in a `std::string`:

```
std::string num;
std::cin >> num;
```

You can do some checks using [`std::isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) and `num.size()` to make sure the input is the correct format. Then each character is simply `num[0] - '0'`, `num[1] - '0'`, and so on. For example, the following would work:

```
auto not_digit = [](char c) { return !std::isdigit(c); };
auto nondigit_iter = std::find_if(num.begin(), num.end(), not_digit);

if (num.size() == 10 && nondigit_iter == num.end()) {
  std::array<int, 10> digits;

  auto digit_to_value = [](char c) { return c - '0'; };
  std::transform(num.begin(), num.end(), digits.begin(), digit_to_value);

  // Now digits contains the 10 values
}
```

You were lucky that the value you gave as an example is actually representable by `double`. Not all integers within the range of `double` are representable. Generally, if you really need integer values, then you want to use an integer type. However, in this case, what you really want is a sequence of 10 digits, rather than a 10 digit value, so you might as well use a `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/ 10` and `% 10` to split the number into digits.

This example illustrates how to find the digits of a long number:

- `2368 / 10` ==> 236

  - `236 / 10` ==> 23

    - `23 / 10` ==> **2**
    - `23 % 10` ==> **3**
  - `236 % 10` ==> **6**
- `2368 % 10` ==> **8**

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (not compiled):

```
int *array = new int[log10(num)];
int temp = int(num);
for(int i=0;temp != 0; i++){
    array[i] = temp%10;
    temp = temp/10; // Integer division
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
int *array[10];
int num;
cin>>num;
for (int i =10; i >= 0; i--) {
    array[i] = num % 10;
    num /= 10;
}
```